Tensor product $\mathbb{Z}^n\otimes \mathbb{Z}^m$
For a problem in my PhD I'm using Leray–Hirsch Theorem (as presented in the Hatcher) to compute a cohomology ring. For a particular group $G$, I have the s.e.s.
$$
\def\Inn{\operatorname{Inn}} 
\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}} 
\def\Out{\operatorname{Out}} 
1 \to \Inn(G) \to \Aut(G) \to \Out(G) \to 1 
$$
since for the s.e.s. the conditions of the theorem hold, we have that
$$
H^*(\Out(G), \mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(\Inn(G), \mathbb{Z}) 
\cong H^*(\Aut(G), \mathbb{Z})
$$
and I know that $H^*(\Out(G), \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $H^*(\Inn(G), \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^m$, for some $m,n$.
My question: Is $H^*(\Aut(G), \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}^k$ for some $k$ depending on $m,n$? I.e., is
$$
\mathbb{Z}^m \otimes \mathbb{Z}^n = \mathbb{Z}^k ?
$$

It seems that you're just asking the (purely algebraic) question about the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}^m \otimes \mathbb{Z}^n$. This is straightforward, as both tensor factors are free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (abelian groups).

I don't know how $Inn$ and $Out$ are defined, but the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}^m$ is $\mathbb{Z}^{nm}$.

Yes: $\mathbb{Z}^n\otimes \mathbb{Z}^m = \mathbb{Z}^{nm}$. You can just write down the expected map and show that it's an isomorphism; alternatively, note that $\mathbb{Z}^n \otimes \mathbb{Z}^m$ is a f.g. torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}$-module and thus isomorphic to some $\mathbb{Z}^k$, and tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ and taking dimensions (of vector spaces) gives $k = nm$. As another alternative, note that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n\otimes \mathbb{Z}^m, A) 
   &= \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n, \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^m, A)) \\
   &= \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, A)^{\oplus m})^{\oplus n} \\
   &= \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, A))^{\oplus nm} \\
   &= \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, A)^{\oplus nm}
\end{align*} for any abelian group $A$, which will characterize $\mathbb{Z}^n\otimes \mathbb{Z}^m$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
